# Creating a collapsible tree view with Angular 2

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I am tring to develop my own collapsible tree view as a way to learn Angular 2. I have it partly working. Right now I am stuck on how to apply the hidden property to on the specific `<li>` item that has been clicked on. Here is what I have so far.

This is the html that displays the items to go in the list.

```
 <div>
     <ol>
          <li *ngFor="let item of videoList">
               <div>
                    <a *ngIf="item.nodes && item.nodes.length > 0" (click)="toggle()">{{item.title}}</a>
                    <a *ngIf="item.nodes <= 0">{{item.title}}</a>
               </div>
               <ol [hidden]="!collapsed">
                    <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.nodes">
                         <a *ngIf="subItem.nodes && subItem.nodes.length > 0" (click)="toggle()">{{subItem.title}}</a>
                         <a *ngIf="subItem.nodes <= 0">{{subItem.title}}</a>
                         <ol [hidden]="!collapsed">
                              <li *ngFor="let video of subItem.nodes">
                                   <a *ngIf="video.nodes && video.nodes.length > 0">{{video.title}}</a>
                                   <a *ngIf="video.nodes <= 0">{{video.title}}</a>
                              </li>
                         </ol>
                    </li>
               </ol>
          </li>
     </ol>
</div>
```

and here is the typescript in the component that collapses or expands the list.

```js
collapased = false;

toggle() {
   this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
    }
```

currently the code collapses and expands the top level elements together and the second level elements together. I need to make each item in the list independent of the other ones. I also prefer to stay away form using CSS to achieve this.

Comment: You are passing something (this) in your subItem node. toggle2 doesn't take arguments, and I'm not sure what you are trying to do with *this*.

Comment: Also, you have two sets of logic for …

Comment: Sorry this was a version I was playing with with I will repost the actual code.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. You have one collapsed variable to rule them all. I think it will make more sense to just use template variables here. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This may throw a kink in the mix but I plan on eventually attempting to make this as dynamic as possible. For instance the can be an "unlimited" depth to he nesting of any node. So if could provide an answer that would possibly scale into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a new property in your front-end model, assuming you are using a front-end model, then you can toggle the items one at a time:

```
export class Item {
    constructor (
        public nodes: Node[],
        public hidden: boolean) {}
}

<div>
     <ol>
          <li *ngFor="let item of videoList">
               <div>
                    <a *ngIf="item.nodes && item.nodes.length > 0" (click)="item.hidden = !item.hidden">{{item.title}}</a>
                    <a *ngIf="item.nodes <= 0">{{item.title}}</a>
               </div>
               <ol [hidden]="!item.hidden">
…
```

If you're not using a model like that, then the only other thing I can think of is creating a unique id tag for each by using whatever unique id comes with your data:

```
<a id="{{node.id}}"> </a>
```

Then you can hide and show based on the id property of those elements. I'm out of ideas, but I'm sure someone else will help!

Comment: This does the same as the original post I had, if you remember. What happens with your answer is this. if there is more then one item say at the second level "showSubItemNodes" when you click on any one of those items in opens all of them. Instead of just the one in question

Comment: Doh. I apologize. You're following the same path I went down a few months ago. My solution was an array of booleans, initializing it to the length of whatever array I was showing, setting them all to false, then toggling them with a function, but there is probably a better way. I did something like: 

`(click)="toggle(video.id)"`

`toggle(id: number) {
   this.showVideo[id] = !this.showVideo[id];
}`

That was frustrating, so I added an extra property on the front end model, *hidden: boolean*, and that allowed me to use a select function to toggle that item's hidden property on and off.

Comment: I actually just figured it out I'll post what i did here.

Comment: I like your answer I think it will help me when moving towards making this dynamic. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have a list of JavaScript objects "hard coded for them moment" each object has properties `id: 1, title: something, collapsed: true, and nodes: []` I added the collapsed property to each node and did the following in my html.

```html
<div>
     <ol>
          <li *ngFor="let item of videoList">
               <div (click)="item.collapsed = !item.collapsed">
                    <a *ngIf="item.nodes && item.nodes.length > 0">{{item.title}}</a>
                    <a *ngIf="item.nodes <= 0">{{item.title}}</a>
               </div>
               <ol >
                    <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.nodes" [hidden]="item.collapsed">
                         <div (click)="subItem.collapsed=!subItem.collapsed">
                              <a *ngIf="subItem.nodes && subItem.nodes.length > 0">{{subItem.title}}</a>
                              <a *ngIf="subItem.nodes <= 0">{{subItem.title}}</a>
                         </div>
                         <ol>
                              <li *ngFor="let video of subItem.nodes" [hidden]="subItem.collapsed">
                                   <div>
                                        <a *ngIf="video.nodes && video.nodes.length > 0">{{video.title}}</a>
                                        <a *ngIf="video.nodes <= 0">{{video.title}}</a>
                                   </div>
                              </li>
                         </ol>
                    </li>
               </ol>
          </li>
     </ol>
</div>
```

basically what is happening is I am changing the collapsed property of the selected node.